# How to search JSON data in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, json, mysql-json

I have inserted records in mysql DB, with `json encoded` data type, Now I have to make search within `json encoded` data, but i am not able to get proper data using following MySql query.

```
SELECT  `id` ,  `attribs_json` 
FROM  `products` 
WHERE  `attribs_json` REGEXP  '"1":{"value":[^"3"$]'
```

Query results are key equal to "1" and value is anything except "3"

My data is:

```
{"feature":{"1":{"value":"["2","3"]"},
            "2":{"value":["1"]},
            "5":{"value":""},
            "3":{"value":["1"]},
            "9":{"value":""},
            "4":{"value":"\u0633\u0627\u062a\u0646"},
            "6":{"value":""},
            "7":{"value":""},
            "8":{"value":""}
           },
"show_counter":"0",
"show_counter_discount":""
}}
```

Comment: i want to show me all record that key is "1" and "3" is one of values

Comment: Explain "can't"! What output do you get?

Comment: i want to show all products that feature's id is 1 and one of feature's values is 3
feature is array like this :
feature = array(
1=>array(1,2,3),2=>array(1,4,7)
) i'm using jsonencode to save it to database

Comment: This sounds like a terrible idea. You would benefit by splitting the data you want to filter into their own columns, and then just using the JSON stuff for additional info you won't filter by.

Comment: why terrible idea.whats Disadvantages of this?

Comment: How's this done in postgresql?

Answer (score 270):

If you have **MySQL version >= 5.7**, then you can try this:

```
SELECT JSON_EXTRACT(name, "$.id") AS name
FROM table
WHERE JSON_EXTRACT(name, "$.id") > 3
```

Output:

```
+-------------------------------+
| name                          | 
+-------------------------------+
| {"id": "4", "name": "Betty"}  | 
+-------------------------------+
```

Please check MySQL reference manual for more details:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-search-functions.html

Comment: Important note: `json_encode` saves integerst as double-quoated values (thus - `string` type).  If searching for equal,  `JSON_EXTRACT(name, "$.id") = "4"` must be used instead of `JSON_EXTRACT(name, "$.id") = 4`

Comment: > In MySQL 5.7.9 and later, the -> operator serves as an alias for the JSON_EXTRACT() function when used with two arguments

Your example then becomes: 

`SELECT name->"$.id" as name FROM table WHERE name->"$.id" > 3`

Personally, I find this easier to follow.

Comment: I guess not possible for MySQL version 4.8.5? So then I'll have to look into a PHP solution.

Comment: Doesn't the double call to `JSON_EXTRACT` increase resource usage? Why not use `HAVING` instead of `WHERE`?

Answer (score 45):

If your are using MySQL Latest version following may help to reach your requirement.

```
select * from products where attribs_json->"$.feature.value[*]" in (1,3)
```

Comment: what do you mean with latest version of mysql ? in what version it is supported ?

Comment: in what version it is IN operator supported ?

Comment: MySQL 5.5 and above @Sérgio

Comment: mysql --version
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.18, for Linux (x86_64) 


Warning: (1235, "This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'comparison of JSON in the IN operator'")

Comment: This is just wrong.

Answer (score 14):

If MySQL version < 5.7

```
SELECT fields
FROM table
WHERE field_json LIKE '%"key":"70"%';
```

// 70 = value

Answer (score 13):

1. Storing JSON in database violates the first normal form.

   The best thing you can do is to normalize and store features in another table. Then you will be able to use a much better looking and performing query with joins.
   Your JSON even resembles the table.
2. Mysql 5.7 has builtin JSON functionality:
   http://mysqlserverteam.com/mysql-5-7-lab-release-json-functions-part-2-querying-json-data/
3. Correct pattern is:

   ```
   WHERE  `attribs_json` REGEXP '"1":{"value":[^}]*"3"[^}]*}'
   ```

   `[^}]` will match any character except `}`

Comment: Agreed on #1 above, but sometimes you have a case where few field names on a table are unknown at design time.  This is a case where you can mix relational and nosql data storage by having a JSON datatype on the table.

Comment: To point 1, the question wasn't about schema design it was about extracting data store as json. Point 2 a link to the answer, Point 3 is fragile in that it could fail if the json changes.

Comment: May I suggest JSON_EXTRACT(attribs_json, '$.feature."1".value') will get at the value of the feature at key "1"

Answer (score 13):

I use this query

```
SELECT id FROM table_name WHERE field_name REGEXP '"key_name":"([^"])key_word([^"])"';
or
SELECT id FROM table_name WHERE field_name RLIKE '"key_name":"[[:<:]]key_word[[:>:]]"';
```

The first query I use it to search partial value. The second query I use it to search exact word.

Comment: MySQL 5.7 finally has JSON support. However will take a while for that update goes mainstream, but as a quick reference this is an easy way to extract some info. Thanks!

Comment: It is not working for me. I have structure like `{"images":"-"}` and `SELECT id FROM parsed_redfin WHERE `data` RLIKE '"images":"[[:<:]]-[[:>:]]"';` is not returning anything

Answer (score 10):

For Mysql8->

Query:

```sql
SELECT properties, properties->"$.price" FROM book where isbn='978-9730228236' and  JSON_EXTRACT(properties, "$.price") > 400;
```

Data:

```
mysql> select * from book\G;
*************************** 1. row ***************************
id: 1
isbn: 978-9730228236
properties: {"price": 44.99, "title": "High-Performance Java Persistence", "author": "Vlad Mihalcea", "publisher": "Amazon"}
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 10):

Please do it like.

```
SELECT * FROM `products` 
    WHERE JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(`attribs_json`, '$.value')) LIKE '%X%'
```

Comment: it may return wrong records of using `'%X%'` unquote if want to find exact value. For example records have value: `2, 52, 100, 200, 300`. We want to find value `2`. By using like `%2%`, we will get result: `2, 52, 200` instead of `2`

Answer (score 6):

```
SELECT
    country.NAME AS 'country_name',
    city.NAME AS 'city_name',
    city.district,
    city.info,
    JSON_EXTRACT( city.info, "$.Population" ) AS 'formated_population' 
FROM
    city
    INNER JOIN country ON city.CountryCode = country.
    CODE INNER JOIN countrylanguage ON country.CODE = countrylanguage.CountryCode 
GROUP BY
    city.NAME,
    city.district,
    country.NAME;

ORDER BY
    country.NAME ASC;
```

[image]

Answer (score -4):

I think...

Search partial value:

```
SELECT id FROM table_name WHERE field_name REGEXP '"key_name":"([^"])*key_word([^"])*"';
```

Search exact word:

```
SELECT id FROM table_name WHERE field_name RLIKE '"key_name":"[[:<:]]key_word[[:>:]]"';
```

Comment: This is exactly the same as one of the already existing answers. There's no need to repeat what Valentino said :)

Answer (score -6):

for MySQL all (and 5.7)

```
SELECT LOWER(TRIM(BOTH 0x22 FROM TRIM(BOTH 0x20 FROM SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING(json_filed,LOCATE('\"ArrayItem\"',json_filed)+LENGTH('\"ArrayItem\"'),LOCATE(0x2C,SUBSTRING(json_filed,LOCATE('\"ArrayItem\"',json_filed)+LENGTH('\"ArrayItem\"')+1,LENGTH(json_filed)))),LOCATE(0x22,SUBSTRING(json_filed,LOCATE('\"ArrayItem\"',json_filed)+LENGTH('\"ArrayItem\"'),LOCATE(0x2C,SUBSTRING(json_filed,LOCATE('\"ArrayItem\"',json_filed)+LENGTH('\"ArrayItem\"')+1,LENGTH(json_filed))))),LENGTH(json_filed))))) AS result FROM `table`;
```