# Check if column containing json string has specific value

Tags: mysql, sql, arrays, json, string

I have a 'jobs' table like this:

```
----------------------------------------------
|job_id |name                    |skills     |
----------------------------------------------
|1      |Job 1                   |[1]        |
|2      |Job 2                   |[2,3]      |
|3      |Job 3                   |[4,5,6]    |
----------------------------------------------
```

The 'skills' column contains a JSON array.

I need to select jobs where one or more skills are met - something like this (but obviously won't work):

```
SELECT * FROM jobs WHERE skills IN (1,4)
```

Should return:

```
----------------------------------------------
|job_id |name                    |skills     |
----------------------------------------------
|1      |Job 1                   |[1]        |
|3      |Job 3                   |[4,5,6]    |
----------------------------------------------
```

Comment: what is your `JSON DATA` column type ?

Comment: it's string type

Comment: They what is your DB ? postgres or mysql ?

Comment: database is mysql

Comment: JSON means this isn't dealt with in the same way. The third answer from: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30411210/how-to-search-json-data-in-mysql looks similar to what you need:
`SELECT * FROM jobs WHERE skills->"$.[*]" in (1,4)` ?

Comment: @SimonLobo what is the version ?

Comment: Unknown column 'skills-' in 'where clause'

Comment: MySQL version 5.7.18

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use **[`REGEXP`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/regexp.html)**

```
select * from jobs where skills REGEXP '[[:<:]]1[[:>:]]|[[:<:]]4[[:>:]]'
```

Append, `[[:<:]]` before and  `[[:>:]]` after, to match exact value and `|` to match for multiple values.

**[>>>Demo<<<](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/39f9f/12)**

Comment: Don't I need to use \b - but can't get it working: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e62bd3/3

Comment: @SimonLobo no. Why do you need that ?

Comment: Otherwise it might match a record 42 when searching for just 4

Answer (score 0):

Either of these queries will return your expected output.

**Option 1**

If `skills` is a string (varchar, text) you could use the `LIKE` string comparison function.

`SELECT * FROM jobs WHERE skills LIKE "%1%" OR skills LIKE "%4%";`

**Option 2**

Or, if you prefer regular expressions, you could use the `REGEXP` function.

`SELECT * FROM jobs WHERE skills REGEXP "1|4";`

Answer (score 0):

Storing JSON on the database is suitable for cases when you don't need to report or query on said fields, since it is less efficient, and doesn't take full advantage of years of query performance optimisations made by the database vendors.
I advice using 2 tables, one for jobs and another for skills, and having a field called job_id on the skills table so you can simply do a query that looks like this:

select jobs.* from jobs where job.id in (select job_id in skill where skill_id in (1,4))

the skill table could later be expanded to have more fields or to be connected to other skills perhaps.

Hope that helps!