# SQL query to select columns with exact like?

Tags: mysql, sql

Consider this SQL table

```
id | name | numbers
------------------------
1 | bob | 1 3 5
2 | joe | 7 2 15
```

This query returns the whole table as its result:

`SELECT * FROM table WHERE numbers LIKE '%5%'`

Is there an SQL operator so that it only returns row 1 (only columns with the number 5)?

Comment: Do not store numbers in a delimited string.  It is a bogosity.  Use a separate table with one row per "name" and "number".

Comment: SELECT * FROM table WHERE numbers LIKE '% 5 %'

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check if column containing json string has specific value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46514613/check-if-column-containing-json-string-has-specific-value)

Comment: If you need to do it once you can use `FIND_IN_SET` with `REPLACE`, but if you need to use it every time - follow @GordonLinoff advice.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I understand it's bogosity and your suggestion is better. If I use a `-`as string delimiter e.g., `-1-3-5-`, `LIKE '%-5-%'` works. It's still a mess but I just want to know if there's any major issues on this bogosity approach? I generally want to stick to 1 table as this is a simple app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `regexp` with word boundaries. (But you should ideally follow Gordon's comment)

```
where numbers REGEXP '[[:<:]]5[[:>:]]'
```

Answer (score 2):

It's a pity that you are not using the comma as a separator in your `numbers` column, because it would be possible to use the `FIND_IN_SET` function, but you can use it together with `REPLACE`, like this:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE FIND_IN_SET(5, REPLACE(numbers, ' ', ','));
```