# PHP SQL - Json like search

Tags: php, sql, arrays, json

I'm sending json via dataloader like this:

```
{"person":{"name":[{"tag":"peter"},{"tag":"frank"},{"tag":"jeff"}]}}
```

I have the below query and as of right now I filter by exact values. But how do I search 'like' for the values this example?

php:

```
...

$arr = json_decode($data,true);

$name = $arr['person']['name'];
foreach($name as $t=>$tag){
    $name[] = $tag['tag'];
}

$query = "SELECT name, id 
          FROM accounts 
          WHERE visible != '1'";
if ($name) {
    $query.=" AND name IN ('".implode("', '", $name)."')"; 
} 
    $query.=" ORDER BY name DESC";

...
```

Comment: I'm afraid you cannot combine `LIKE` with `IN` - at least not that I know. You'd have to build a `LIKE 'xy' OR LIKE 'z' OR...` query

Comment: maybe even fill text matching depeding on your needs: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-search.html

Comment: what is the foreach for? right now you are just doubling the entries!? You are sure you wanna add the `$name` inside the loop?

Comment: Sorry I should have mentioned ... I send the data via json and dataloader ... I edited above.

Answer (score 0):

Adding an OR and the REGEXP function will allow both exact and like.

```
$query.=" AND name IN ('".implode(', ', $name)."') OR name REGEXP ('".implode('|', $name)."')";
```

Comment: Sorry I should have mentioned ... I send the data via json and dataloader ... I edited above. Does your example still fit?

Comment: yes, the example still fits. Its only altering what's going on in your query string. This just grabs your name array and splits it 2 times, once for the = search, and again for the like regexp

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically and not recommended since it will not be very performant, you could use `OR` (not tested):

```
$name = $arr['person']['name'];

if ($name) {
  $arr = [];
  foreach($name as $t=>$tag){
    $n = $tag['tag'];
    $arr[] = “(name LIKE ‘%$n%’)”;
  }
  $query .= “ AND (“ . implode(“ OR “, $arr) . “)”;
}
```

But I think you should re-structure your data to either use JSON column and then you could search the data (e.g. take a look at this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30411210/how-to-search-json-data-in-mysql)).

Or the other option (which complies more to a normalized db structure) is to put the names in their own table, join the table to the accounts table and search do a simple LIKE search.

Comment: I do send the data via json and dataloader ... I edited above. Does your example still fit?

Answer (score 0):

Loop your name array to create a new array with LIKE operator and implode it with OR operator in your query.

```
$data = '{"person":{"name":[{"tag":"peter"},{"tag":"frank"},{"tag":"jeff"}]}}';

$arr = json_decode($data,true);

$name = $arr['person']['name'];
$search_term =array();
// loop it to add like operator
foreach($name as $t=>$tag){
    $search_term[] = "name LIKE '%".$tag['tag']."%'";
}

$query = "SELECT name, id FROM accounts WHERE visible != '1'";
if (!empty($search_term)) {
    // implode you like with or operator   
    $query.=" AND ".implode( ' OR ' , $search_term); 
} 
$query.=" ORDER BY name DESC";

echo $query;

SELECT name, id FROM accounts WHERE visible != '1' AND name LIKE '%peter%' OR name LIKE '%frank%' OR name LIKE '%jeff%' ORDER BY name DESC
```

Comment: Sorry I should have mentioned ... I send the data via json and dataloader ... I edited above. Does your example still fit?

Comment: Updated answer.