# Mapping MySQL JSON column to hibernate value type

Tags: java, mysql, json, hibernate, jpa

What is the best practice for working with JSON column within Java code? Specifically I am interested in being able to save & query JSON columns in a MySQL DB using hibernate..

```
@Entity
public class MyEntity {

    private String myField; // this field is a json column

    public MyEntity() {
    }
}
```

Comment: Elaborate on "working with".

Comment: If you're using the JSR-353 `javax.json` classes, then there is one way to automate the conversion to and from strings by just adding this dependency to your project http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.mopano/hibernate-json-contributor/1.0
Otherwise, you'll just have to use manual conversion or try and hope that a JPA AttributeConverter works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a good library to deal with JSON types in Hibernate. It's called [Hibernate Types](https://vladmihalcea.com/how-to-map-json-objects-using-generic-hibernate-types/), and you can scroll down to the MySQL section to get the right example.

And some samples of usage MySQL's JSON API inside query:

[How to search JSON data in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30411210/how-to-search-json-data-in-mysql)

Comment: I get exceptions when using this library with values that are set to null or objects that are nested more than one layer deep. Anyone have any ideas on that?

Comment: @DanielPatrick , this library is based on common Jackson library, so at least issue with null could be solved by proper Jackson mapper configuration https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.0.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonInclude.Include.html . Will be good to see an error trace actually to be more specific.