# JSON_CONTAINS unable to find from MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, json, mysql-json

In MySQL I'm storing the data within "jsonValues" field with PHP's json_encode:

```
{"product_category":[[{"category":["28"]},{"product":["16","22","64"]}]]}
```

Through PHP, I want to get the data by writing the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM `dbTable` 
WHERE JSON_CONTAINS(jsonValues, '"category":["28"]');
```

However, it shows the **error**:

> ## 3141 - Invalid JSON text in argument 2 to function json_contains: "The document root must not follow by other values." at position 10.

Comment: Why are you storing JSON in your DB? Can't you store them in a proper DB schema? `JSON_CONTAINS` is probably not what you want, you might be searching for `JSON_EXTRACT`. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/39163928/3223157 on how to use it.

Comment: @Xatenev I can't because the information which I need to be stored can't be stored into the proper db schema as these are not identical.

Comment: See edit of my 1st comment.

Comment: Have a try of something like this 
`SELECT * FROM 'dbTable' 
WHERE JSON_CONTAINS(jsonValues, '$.category');`
Reference:[https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-search-functions.html#function_json-contains]

Comment: I already tried but returns  nothing. `SELECT * FROM `dbTable` 
WHERE JSON_CONTAINS(jsonValues, '["28"]', '$.shipping_location');`

Comment: Have you tried this way `SELECT * FROM 'dbTable' 
WHERE JSON_CONTAINS(jsonValues, '{"category":"28"}');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It returns the row after writing the below codes:

```
SELECT * FROM `dbTable` WHERE JSON_CONTAINS(jsonValues, '{"category":["28"]}', '$.product_category');
```

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried adding the curly brackets around your search term, as the mysql doc does?

```
SELECT * FROM `dbTable` WHERE JSON_CONTAINS(jsonValues, '{"category":["28"]}');
```

Comment: Thanks for this but it also returns nothing.

Comment: Is anything wrong in my jsonValues as mentioned in my question?

Answer (score 1):

If None of the above method works for you then try below code it should work.

`SELECT * FROM`dbTable
`WHERE JSON_CONTAINS(jsonValues, '{"product_category": [[{"category": ["28"]}]]}');`

Answer (score 1):

i was having the same problem,
i was saving data as follows in the DB,

```
$id = '1';
json_encode(array($id)); //in DB it stores like this => ["1"]
```

I changed this to

```
$id = '1';
json_encode(array(intval($id))); //in DB it stores like this => [1]
```

Then this query works perfectly.

```
Select * from table where WHERE JSON_CONTAINS(json_col, '$id');
```

I hope it will help someone in future.