# JSON_SEARCH in MySQL

Tags: mysql, json

I have a `MySQL` table with `JSON` data and I'm trying to get the path to a value saved in `JSON`. But I am not able to do that.

I just have one window:

```
+----------------------------------------------------------------------
| info
+----------------------------------------------------------------------
|  [{"id": "1","name":"firstname","value":"firstvalue"}, 
|  {"id":"0","name":"secondname","value":"secondvalue"}] 
+----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

and I'm trying to get path to value "1" of key "id" by:

```
SELECT JSON_SEARCH(info, "all", "1", NULL, "$*.id")
```

There is no problem with selecting window, but with `JSON_SEARCH` command (I always get *NULL*). What do I do wrong?

It is not [How to search JSON data in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30411210/how-to-search-json-data-in-mysql).

Comment: It's a duplicated question. Refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30411210/how-to-search-json-data-in-mysql

Comment: @caot Which answer there shows how to fix this?

Comment: @caot No, it's another problem...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to search JSON data in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30411210/how-to-search-json-data-in-mysql)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The path should be `$[*].id` to indicate that you want to search the `id` property of all array elements.

```
SELECT JSON_SEARCH(info, "all", "1", null, '$[*].id')
```

Comment: Thank you a lot! Is there a way to get the "$[0].id" without ".id"?

Comment: You can leave out the path entirely, but then it might find `1` in some other property that you don't care about.