# Parse json array to find Id

Tags: php, laravel

So I'm new in laravel and I'm trying to create a rest api to return a specific item of my data database

http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/items/1010100203

And I'm getting []

So I have a array of json objects like

```
[{"No_":"1010100203","Price:"23","Description":"Item1"},{"No_":"1010100204","Price":"15","Description":"Item2"},{"No_":"1010100205","Price":"12","Description":"Item3"}]
```

in my database and I want to get my item with "No_" 1010100203.

In controller I have this function

```
public function find($id){

         return Item::where('No_', 'like', $id)->get();
     }
```

I've also tried to create a find function to only return $item and also returned []

I think I need to parse my array but I don't know how to do this..

And in my route api file,

```
Route::get('items/{id}', 'ItemController@find');
```

Also tried with Manager,

```
 ItemController,

    public function find($id){
            $im= new ItemManager();
            if (!empty($id))
                $i=$im->GetItemIfExist($id);

             return $i;
         }

ItemManager
   public function GetItemIfExist($id){
         $result=\Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB::table('MR$Item')
         ->where('No_',$id)
         ->get();

         return $result;
     }
```

Comment: Is that json just a return of all the objects in your table, or is that json in one field in your table?

Comment: So, you have JSON in your DB? https://stackoverflow.com/a/39163928/2191572

Comment: This is the return of all my data in my table (/items/)

Comment: My database dont have json.. is a table with fields.. the return when I make /items is a array of json

Answer (score -1):

Why you use 'like'? Use '=' if you need exact match

Comment: Its the same.. if i use = instead of like the return is []