# How to make select query of table that has JSON data in a column

Tags: json, postgresql, amazon-rds

I have the column name **devices** in one table. In this column, I have JSON Data like this for each row

```
{"os": "Apple iPhone", "mac_address": "58:7f:57:d7:32:f2", "manufacturer": "Apple"}
```

[image]

If I Want to check whether the mac_address is present in that cell that has this JSON data or not, which query should I make? ( IF it is not present then the whole cell will be NULL.)

This is the task.

***retrieve id for each mac address from users table in rds db (if available). if not available, new row should be inserted and id created;***

Comment: you can find the answer easily from google search like "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30411210/how-to-search-json-data-in-mysql"

Comment: In MySQL use `json_column->>"$.mac_address" IS NOT NULL`

Comment: I removed the conflicting DBMS tags. Please add only the tag for the database product you are really using. (When it comes to JSON support the concrete DBMS product matters)

Comment: In Postgres, use `json_column ? 'mac_address'`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I am using Amazon RDS with Postgres

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT id from users WHERE devices ->> 'mac_address' = '58:32f:22:d3:32:f2';
```

Did it this way and it worked.