# MYSQL Json query

Tags: mysql, sql, json

I have a JSON array of objects in a MySQL table that I am trying to see if there is a way to query and just pull the data.  For example.

JSON Array Object

```
email_address_dump
[{"value":"a123@yahoo.com","type":"personal"},{"value":"all123@hotmail.com","type":"personal"},{"value":"car_sq5@indeedemail.com","type":"personal"}]
```

is there a way to query out just the email address?  so that the results can be something like this?

```
a123@yahoo.com, all123@hotmail.com, car_sq5@indeedemail.com
```

I am not trying to search within the column, I know that with JSON Obtains you can use a where clause, this is more of a JSON Extract.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to search JSON data in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30411210/how-to-search-json-data-in-mysql)

Comment: @JohnHC no, I am not trying to search but to extract the data.  I think I found the answer by doing JSON Extract.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve this by using JSON Extract from MySQL.

json_extract(c.email_address_dump, ''$[*].value') as EmailAddressArray,