# Laravel MongoDB search array value in column

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, mongodb

I am trying to search data in column that has array data type.

```
[
  {
    "_id": 1,
    "types: [
      ["4","5","6"], ["7","8","9"]
    ]
  },
  {
    "_id": 2,
    "types: [
      ["4","1","2"], ["7","8","9"]
    ]
  },
  {
    "_id": 3,
    "types: [
      ["6","1","2"], ["7","8","9"]
    ]
  },
]
```

I want to query data that column named `types` contains value "4". So it will return

```
[
  {
    "_id": 1,
    "types: [
      ["4","5","6"], ["7","8","9"]
    ]
  },
  {
    "_id": 2,
    "types: [
      ["4","1","2"], ["7","8","9"]
    ]
  },
]
```

This is what I've tried but it does not work.
`Employee::where('types', '=', $num)->get();`

Comment: So the data is stored in json in the columns?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to search JSON data in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30411210/how-to-search-json-data-in-mysql)

Comment: @nice_dev yes, it is.

Answer (score 0):

Cause the value of the type is an array, = can't be a solution. I think you should make a foreach loop with types values and compare them with your required value.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).