# SQL: json_extract a key from a every field in a list

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-json

Hey I have a table with two columns - A and B. Column A is a VARCHAR. Column B has stringified list of jsons. The size of the list varies. Every JSON has a key called "foo". As a part of a query, I want to check if A = any of the foo values
So somehow get all the "foo" values from every json in a list and then maybe use a WHERE IN condition

Comment: Wich version of MySQL are you using? In any case, this seems to be a problem for the business datalayer, not the database

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to search JSON data in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30411210/how-to-search-json-data-in-mysql)

Comment: It would help if you show a mock-up example of your JSON. It's not clear from your question how the JSON is structured. You say it has a key "foo" but you also mention "any of the foo values." Does that mean the "foo" key has an array value? This would be cleared up if you show an example.

Comment: Also please state what `SELECT VERSION();` returns, because the answer could depend on what exact database version you use.

Comment: Sorry, @Sid. I downvoted your question. Please, be more specific and provide sample data and the code you wrote so far. Ok, we are genius, we can make abstractions and decisions. But, man, it's not funny. 'Foo', 'A', 'B'.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `json_table` in a subquery:

```
select t.a, exists (select 1 from json_table(t.b, '$[*]' columns (foo text path '$.foo')) t3 
where t3.foo = t.a) from tbl t
```

See fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=f654b193dc1878b3fee8e0eb35f0e068).

Comment: Hey @Ajax1234 , this code snippet isnt working. Is the code inside columns correct syntax?

Comment: @SidAnand What is the error/output issue that you have recieved? Also, please post a sample of your db data itself.

Comment: Hey @Ajax1234, I am using SQLite in nodejs (version 3.0.3). Here is the fiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=f654b193dc1878b3fee8e0eb35f0e068

Comment: @SidAnand Your original question was tagged `mysql`, `json_table` is not compatible with `sqlite`.