# how to convert mysql json_object to string?

Tags: mysql

Supposed I have data below, `select * from json_value_table`:

```
id   json_value
1   {"name":"some value","price":50}    
2   {"name":"some value","price":100}   
3   {"name":"some value","price":150}   
4   {"name":"some value","price":250}
```

I need the output as below：

```
id  name         pirce
1   some value   50
2   some value   100
3   some value   150
4   some value   250
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to search JSON data in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30411210/how-to-search-json-data-in-mysql)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JSON_EXTRACT() returns a JSON scalar (i.e. a double-quoted string like `"some value"`), which is technically a JSON document. If you want a plain string, also use JSON_UNQUOTE().

```
SELECT id, 
 JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(json_value,'$.name')) AS name, 
 JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(json_value,'$.price')) AS price 
FROM json_value_table;
```

MySQL has shortcut syntax for this:

```
SELECT id, 
 json_value->>'$.name' AS name, 
 json_value->>'$.price' AS price 
FROM json_value_table;
```

This is in the manual by the way: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-search-functions.html#operator_json-inline-path

Comment: Line #3 alias should be `AS pirce`, according to the requirements given :)

Comment: @MattDavey, I like to follow the Boy Scout rule — leave the camp site cleaner than you found it. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```sql
SELECT id, JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(json_value,'$.name')) AS name, JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(json_value,'$.price')) AS price FROM json_value_table;
```

Comment: Thanks so much, can I remove quotation mark of "some value"?

Comment: No, because it will break the JSON format.

Comment: User this, `JSON_UNQUOTE(json_extract(json_value,'$.name'))`

Comment: I see, good way