# How to multiple array of json values in MYSQL?

Tags: sql, mysql

I've a column that contain json values like

```
[
  {
    "name": "enabled",
    "value": "true",
    "type": "boolean"
  },
  {
    "name": "limit_amount_per_day",
    "value": "100",
    "type": "text",
    "pattern": "^[0-9]*$",
    "min": "0",
    "max": "100000"
  },
  {
    "name": "limit_amount_per_month",
    "value": "1000",
    "type": "text",
    "pattern": "^[0-9]*$",
    "min": "0",
    "max": "100000"
  },
]
```

or can be in

```
[{"name": "enabled", "value": "true", "type": "boolean"}, {"name": "limit_amount_per_day", "value": "100", "type": "text", "pattern": "^[0-9]*$", "min": "0", "max": "100000"}, {"name": "limit_amount_per_month", "value": "1000", "type": "text", "pattern": "^[0-9]*$", "min": "0", "max": "100000"},]
```

How can I query inside column in sql ?

For example... from that json , i want to get value that contains name 'enabled' so i could use it in another queries.

What i've tried was
`SELECT * FROM SOME_TABLE where value LIKE '%"name":"enabled", "value": "boolean"%'`
but it is very error prone .

Anybody can find out way with this?

Comment: Duplicate [How to search JSON data in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30411210/how-to-search-json-data-in-mysql)

Answer (score 1):

Using [`json_table`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-table-functions.html):

```
select k.value from test t 
cross join json_table(t.js, '$[*]' columns (name text path '$.name', value 
    text path '$.value')) k
where k.name = 'enabled'
```

[See fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Oqz2iCO5)